# Populate a temporary table with data from another table using SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I want to populate my temporary table (tmp) with the result of the SELECT statement based on the species of the pet from the pets table. But I am getting NULL for all columns
This is my CREATE TABLE with the queries I have written so far

```
create table pets ( name varchar(255), species varchar(255) );

insert into pets (name, species) values ('Barker', 'weasel'), ('Chevy', 'chinchilla'), ('Fay', 'chinchilla'), ('Grit', 'cat'), ('Hex', 'dog'), ('Lunar', 'dog'), ('Mojo', 'chinchilla'), ('Peter', 'weasel'), ('Shogun', 'cat'), ('Sierra', 'cat');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
cats VARCHAR(255), 
dogs VARCHAR(255), 
weasels VARCHAR(255), 
chinchillas VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO tmp(cats, dogs, weasels, chinchillas) 
VALUES
(
 (SELECT name FROM pets WHERE species IN (SELECT name FROM pets WHERE species = 'cat')),
 (SELECT name FROM pets WHERE species IN (SELECT name FROM pets WHERE species = 'dog')),
 (SELECT name FROM pets WHERE species IN (SELECT name FROM pets WHERE species = 'weasel')),
 (SELECT name FROM pets WHERE species IN (SELECT name FROM pets WHERE species = 'chinchilla'))
);


SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

[I want to achieve the expected output in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4wKG.png)

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: @FanoFN MySQL is 8.0

Comment: Is there a way to use stored procedures to achieve the same goal?

Comment: I'm not sure about stored procedure because I don't have extensive experience using it but if you mean prepared statement, then yes, this is achievable.

Comment: @FanoFN How do I replace 'null' with 'NULL' in the rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3iTPpgXuMbM5Qo5Cn26zVZ/1))

```
INSERT INTO tmp(cats, dogs, weasels, chinchillas) 
SELECT 
 case species when 'cat' then name else '' end,
 case species when 'dog' then name else '' end,
 case species when 'weasel' then name else '' end,
 case species when 'chinchilla' then name else '' end
from pets;
```

Comment: How do I remove the empty rows from the temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated but it's possible like this:

```
INSERT INTO tmp(cats, dogs, weasels, chinchillas) 
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN species='cat' 
             THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sname,',',seq),',',-1) END) AS 'cats',
       MAX(CASE WHEN species='dog' 
             THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sname,',',seq),',',-1) END) AS 'dogs',
       MAX(CASE WHEN species='weasel' 
             THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sname,',',seq),',',-1) END) AS 'weasel',
       MAX(CASE WHEN species='chinchilla' 
             THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sname,',',seq),',',-1) END) AS 'chinchillas' 
  FROM
  (SELECT species, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS sname,
       COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM pets
   GROUP BY species) p 
 JOIN 
  (SELECT 1 seq UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) s
    ON seq <= cnt
GROUP BY seq
ORDER BY seq;
```

The base query component is:

```
SELECT species, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS sname,
       COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM pets
   GROUP BY species
```

That will return the following result:

| species | sname | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | Grit,Shogun,Sierra | 3 |
| chinchilla | Chevy,Fay,Mojo | 3 |
| dog | Hex,Lunar | 2 |
| weasel | Barker,Peter | 2 |

Make that as a subquery then add a query to generate a custom number sequences to `JOIN` with the base query:

```
(SELECT 1 seq UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) s
/*with ON like this*/
  ON seq <= cnt
```

The main highlight here is probably the `MAX(CASE ..` expression in `SELECT`. We're doing `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` twice and make use of the custom generated sequence numbers to obtain which part of the group concatenated value of `sname` to get.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=930ccdd1eb41e4b8185471e99bbaefed)

Comment: Thanks @FanoFn, It worked perfectly. This is indeed complicated

Comment: how do I replace null with NULL in the rows?

Comment: You can add `IFNULL(MAX(CASE ....), 'NULL')`  [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3bba9cc95acd7b8378a44f47471b5079)